# How do I get name of computer to display in arp-scan?

Tags: networking

I have an ubuntu laptop and an ubuntu desktop; I have both ethernet and WiFi.  When I connect them both to the ethernet router, my desktop and laptop IP addresses display.  However, there is no name next to the IP addresses. I see that my "NETGEAR" device *is* displaying a name though.

How do I reproduce this with my desktop?  I added the IP address and computer name to the hosts file in `/etc/hosts`, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/hosts` file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   HOSTNAMEHERE

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

and your `/etc/hostname` file should look like this:

```
HOSTNAMEHERE
```

Comment: Hmm...it has an entry in /etc/hostname and in hosts...

Comment: btw, does it matter if I open port 22 for ssh when I am on the local network? or do I have to use the public key?